# Why do I receive file share error if Sql Compact allows multiple connections?

Tags: sql-server-ce, database-connection

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645984.aspx), it is said that Sql Server Compact allows up to 256 connections.

But when I try to open 2 connections, I receive a file sharing error. How can I solve this?

```
SqlCeConnection c1 = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=testDB.sdf;Encrypt Database=True;Password=test;File Mode=shared read;Persist Security Info=False;");
SqlCeConnection c2 = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=testDB.sdf;Encrypt Database=True;Password=test;File Mode=shared read;Persist Security Info=False;");
c1.Open();
c2.Open(); // throws SqlCeException
c1.Close();
c2.Close();
```

*There is a file sharing violation. A different process might be using the file. [ testDB.sdf ]*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a connection string issue.

```
File Mode=Read Write
```

solved the problem.

Comment: I just had this same problem. Stupid mistake really... thanks for putting me right.

Comment: I got the same error using SQL compact 4.0 for a small website with concurrent users.  This suggestion did not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

When survey this problem, I find some resources and this post. Maybe someone will need it, so I leave what I find here.

[According the MSDN said](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if no `File Mode` assigned, it will use `Read Write` by default.

And, if need to open a `Read Only` db, [this post said two parameters should be assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289355/open-sql-server-ce-database-data-from-read-only-file-system/11289707#11289707). One is `File Mode`, and one is `Temp Path`.